# Two Sum: How is the solution with O(1) space complexity implemented?

Tags: java

The classical Two Sum problem is described in [LeetCode](http://oj.leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/).

I know how to solve it with a hash table, which results in O(n) extra space. Now I want to solve it with O(1) space, so I'll first sort the array and then use two pointers to find the two integers, as shown in the (incorrect) code below.

```
public int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
        java.util.Arrays.sort(numbers);
        int start = 0, end = numbers.length - 1;
        while(start < end) {
            if(numbers[start] + numbers[end] < target) {
                start++;
            }
            else if(numbers[start] + numbers[end] > target) {
                end--;
            }
            else {
                int[] result = {start + 1, end + 1};
                return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
}
```

This code is incorrect: I'm returning the indices after sorting. So how will I keep track of the original indices of the selected integers? Or are there other O(1) space solutions? Thank you.

Comment: If all you care about is space, then two nested loops would do it (somewhat similar to bubble sort approach).

Comment: It seems like cheating if you can use the O(n) space in the given array. I think a true O(1) solution would refer to having a fixed amount of space and only reading at most that much input at once. (Like an online algorithm)

Comment: Also, keep in mind that `Arrays.sort` adds space larger than O(1). Most of the time it uses a variant of quicksort, so around O(log n) extra space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are only worried about space complexity, and not the time complexity, then you don't need to sort. That way, the whole issue of keeping track of original indices goes away.

```
int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length-1; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
            if (numbers[i] + numbers[j] == target)
                return new int[]{i+1, j+1};
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

If you want to return all such pairs, not just the first one, then just continue with the iterations instead of returning immediately (of course, the return type will have to change to a list or 2-d array or ... ).

Comment: Thank you so much. Just to confirm: Does that mean I can't do better than O(n^2) time if I insist on O(1) space?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I can't think of a way to reduce the time complexity. As Buddha's answer mentions, there's almost always a trade-off between time and space complexity.

Answer (score 4):

There are certain limits what can be achieved and what can't be. There are some parameters that depend on each other. Time & Space complexities are two such parameters when it comes to algorithms.

If you want to optimize your problem for space, it will increase the time complexity in most of the cases except in some special circumstances.

In this problem, if you don't want to increase the space complexity and want to preserve the original indices, the only way to do it is to not sort the array and take every two numbers combinations from the array and check if their sum is your target. This means the code becomes something similar to below.

```
while(i < n)
{
   while(j < n)
   {
      if(i!=j && arr[i]+arr[j]==target)
      {
            int[] result = {i, j};
                return result;
      }
      j++;
   }
   i++;
}
```

As you can see this obviously is an O(n^2) algorithm. Even in the program you have written the sorting will be something like O(nlogn).

So, the bottom line is if you want to reduce space complexity, it increases time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int i =0;
        int j = 1;
        vector<int> v;
        while( i < nums.size() && j < nums.size() ){
            if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target && i != j){
                v.push_back(i);
                v.push_back(j);
                break;
            }
            else if(j < nums.size()-1){
                j++;
                continue;
            }
            i++;
            j=1;
        }

        return v;  
    }
};
```